# How do I group answers in categories JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I'm working on my graduation project for my bachelor of ICT and bachelor of Education. Therefor I'm making a 'quiz' on the base of which students can be assessed on their progress concerning the new competences of the 21st century skills.

I've read a great article from Yaphi Berhanu on SitePoint [(https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-javascript-quiz/)](https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-javascript-quiz/)  which made it possible to print the questions on the screen and store the amount of correct answers.

For this project I need to add variable 'category' to store the amount of correct answers to a specific category.

Till today I tweaked the code to a quiz that's storing the results in 6 different hidden input values. But still it doesn't store the results in the right category.

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: category is not defined"

How/where do I define the 'category' variable?

The codesnippet is below:

```js
(function() {
  const myQuestions = [{
      question: "",
      category: "1",
      answers: {
        a: "Superman",
        b: "The Terminator",
        c: "Waluigi, obviously"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "",
      category: "2",
      answers: {
        a: "SitePoint",
        b: "Simple Steps Code",
        c: "Trick question; they're both the best"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "",
      category: "3",
      answers: {
        a: "Antarctica",
        b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
        c: "Sitting in a tree",
        d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "",
      category: "4",
      answers: {
        a: "Antarctica",
        b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
        c: "Sitting in a tree",
        d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "",
      category: "5",
      answers: {
        a: "Antarctica",
        b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
        c: "Sitting in a tree",
        d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "",
      category: "6",
      answers: {
        a: "Antarctica",
        b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
        c: "Sitting in a tree",
        d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    }
  ];

  function buildQuiz() {
    // we'll need a place to store the HTML output
    const output = [];


    // for each question...
    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
      // we'll want to store the list of answer choices
      const answers = [];

      // here we store the questioncategory
      const category = [];

      // and for each available answer...
      for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
        // ...add an HTML radio button
        answers.push(
          `<label>
             <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
              ${letter} :
              ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
           </label>`
        );
      }

      // add this question and its answers to the output
      output.push(
        `<div class="slide">
           <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
           <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
         </div>`
      );
    });

    // finally combine our output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
  }

  function showResults() {
    // gather answer containers from our quiz
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll(".answers");

    // keep track of user's answers
    let numCorrect1 = 0;
    let numCorrect2 = 0;
    let numCorrect3 = 0;
    let numCorrect4 = 0;
    let numCorrect5 = 0;
    let numCorrect6 = 0;

    // for each question...
    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
      // find selected answer
      const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
      const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
      const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;

      // if answer is correct
      if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
        // add to the number of correct answers
        if (category === 1) {
          numCorrect1++;
        }
        if (category === 2) {
          numCorrect2++;
        }
        if (category === 3) {
          numCorrect3++;
        }
        if (category === 4) {
          numCorrect4++;
        }
        if (category === 5) {
          numCorrect5++;
        }
        if (category === 6) {
          numCorrect6++;
        }

        // color the answers green
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "lightgreen";
      } else {
        // if answer is wrong or blank
        // color the answers red
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "red";
      }
    });

    // show number of correct answers out of total
    resultsContainer1.value = `${numCorrect1}`;
    resultsContainer2.value = `${numCorrect2}`;
    resultsContainer3.value = `${numCorrect3}`;
    resultsContainer4.value = `${numCorrect4}`;
    resultsContainer5.value = `${numCorrect5}`;
    resultsContainer6.value = `${numCorrect6}`;
  }

  function showSlide(n) {
    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("active-slide");
    slides[n].classList.add("active-slide");
    currentSlide = n;

    if (currentSlide === 0) {
      previousButton.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      previousButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    }

    if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) {
      nextButton.style.display = "none";
      previousButton.style.display = "none";
      submitButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      nextButton.style.display = "inline-block";
      submitButton.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  function showNextSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
  }

  function showPreviousSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }

  const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
  const resultsContainer1 = document.getElementById("results1");
  const resultsContainer2 = document.getElementById("results2");
  const resultsContainer3 = document.getElementById("results3");
  const resultsContainer4 = document.getElementById("results4");
  const resultsContainer5 = document.getElementById("results5");
  const resultsContainer6 = document.getElementById("results6");
  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

  // display quiz right away
  buildQuiz();

  const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
  const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  let currentSlide = 0;

  showSlide(0);

  // on submit, show results
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
})();
```

```css
.question {
  font-size: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.answers {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.answers label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.active-slide {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.quiz-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz-container">
  <div id="quiz"></div>
</div>
<button class="w3-button w3-block w3-blue w3-section w3-padding w3-half" type="button" id="previous"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Vorige</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-block w3-blue w3-section w3-padding w3-half" type="button" id="next">Volgende <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
<button class="w3-button w3-block w3-blue w3-section w3-padding" type="button" id="submit" name="submit">Verzenden</button>
<input id="results1" type="hidden" name="1" value="">
<input id="results2" type="hidden" name="2" value="">
<input id="results3" type="hidden" name="3" value="">
<input id="results4" type="hidden" name="4" value="">
<input id="results5" type="hidden" name="5" value="">
<input id="results6" type="hidden" name="6" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="usrname" value="">
```

Comment: Give each hidden input the class `.category` Then collect then with this: var cats = document. **querySelectorAll** ('.category'). At this point you need to iterate through the result with a **for loop** or **convert the NodeList into an array** in order to manipulate you results. You have to learn fundamentals I advise that you google the bold words in this comment.

Comment: I've come so far that I added the classes, collected them with a variable trough  **document.querySelectorAll('.category');** and dump them a for loop like so: _if (category === 1) {
        // add to the number of correct answers
        if(userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) { 
            numCorrect1++;
        }
          else {
        // if answer is wrong or blank
        // color the answers red
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "red";
        }  
      }_  Now I end up getting each value as 0 in the hidden input. Still doing something wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Reference Errors are usually easy to find: you're using a variable/object you haven't declared in your code.

The culprit is in your `showResults()` method, below snippet should work. I've changed `category` into `currentQuestion.category`.

Also, try to standardize your code a bit, it's weird to read now. You're using anonymous functions and normal for loops interchangeably, use comments to clarify "bad" variable names, etc. [Style Guides](https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript%20style%20guide) can help you with this.

```js
  function showResults() {

// ...

myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
  const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
  const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
  const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;

  // if answer is correct
  if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
    // add to the number of correct answers
    if (currentQuestion.category == 1) {
        numCorrect1++;
    }
    if (currentQuestion.category == 2) {
        numCorrect2++;
    }
    if (currentQuestion.category == 3) {
        numCorrect3++;
    }
    if (currentQuestion.category == 4) {
        numCorrect4++;
    }
    if (currentQuestion.category == 5) {
        numCorrect5++;
    }
    if (currentQuestion.category == 6) {
        numCorrect6++;
    }

    // color the answers green
    answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "lightgreen";
  } else {
    // if answer is wrong or blank
    // color the answers red
    answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "red";
  }
});

// ...
  }
```

Comment: The collours seem to work. But still posting the 0 inside the hidden values. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1x5e723/2/) I've changed the hidden values to 'text' so you can see the changes.

Comment: Updated my answer. Change the `===` in the category checks for `==`. You were comparing `"1"` to `1`, which is going to fail. `==` checks loosely and thus accepts the comparison.